# Подсчет созданных экземпляров без статики

Tags: java, ооп, static, variable, core

Задумался как реализовать подсчет экземпляров классов, для каждого отдельно разумеется, без использования статических переменных. Задача проста: создаём класс, создаём экземпляр класса, инкрементим  переменную (или каким то другим способом). На учебе это делалось статической переменной, которая инкрементилась в конструкторе, но мне кажется это неправильный подход. Какая логика реализации этого на чистом ООП подходе? Спасибо

Comment: Возможно вам вот такая консольная команда подойдёт: `jmap -histo <PDID>` В крайнем случае её можно попробовать и из приложения прямо вызвать. А вообще, возможно, вы сможете даже получить более-менее подходящий ответ, если опишите какую задачу вы хотите решить таким способом. Возможно её надо не так решать или вообще решать не надо.

Comment: Юрий, спасибо за ответ, вопрос был дополнен

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть много вариантов

1. Статическая переменная это тоже ООП. Только там нет группировки объектов класса
2. Есть вариант использовать singleton. Создается класс для подсчета объектов. И у конструктора можете вызвать singleton класс (другой класс) и там делаете инкремент.
   Таким образом вы можете группировать ваши объекты из одного того же класса

```
public class SingleObject {

   private static SingleObject instance = new SingleObject();
   private AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(0);

   private SingleObject(){}

   public static SingleObject getInstance(){
      counter.increment();
      return instance;
   }

}
```